# C++ Print reversed integer with recursion

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am trying to reverse an integer on c++ without using loops. I thought I had the right idea here but it does not work as I wanted. If anyone could show me what looks wrong here would greatly appreciate it

```
void reverse(int y){ //base
   int a = y % 10; 
   int length = to_string(y).length();
   cout << length << endl;//gets length of number
   cout << reversed << endl;
   reversed += a * (10 ^ (length - 1)); // add to reversed
   y = y / 10;
   if (y == 0){
      cout << reversed  << endl;
      exit (0);
   }
   else { //recursive
      reverse (y);
   }
}
```

Comment: How can this compile. You use a variable called reversed but it isn't defined anywhere.  Can you please show us all the code?

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. It does not do exponentiation.

Comment: Look at the value of a. That might be useful. Then what happens if you divide by 10?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve]. Posting bits and pieces of code that cannot be compiled is not helpful.

Comment: Change the line that calculates the length to `int length = log10(y)+1;` and change the line that calculates reversed to `reversed += a * pow(10,length - 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out ^ is not the power operator. Use pow() of  for example.

This should work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int reversed;

void reverse(int y){ //base
   int a = y % 10;
   reversed += a * pow(10, to_string(y).length()-1); // add to reversed
    y = y / 10;
       //Condition, digit must be 1 number
    if (y >= 10){
        cout << reversed << endl;
        reverse(y);
   } else {
       cout << reversed << endl;
       reversed += y;
       cout << reversed << endl;
   }
}


int main() {
    reverse(123456);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
600000
650000
654000
654300
654320
654321
```